# C/C++ binary data (PDF) base64 encode-decode

Tags: c++, encoding

I'm trying to convert some binary data (PDF file) to base64 encoding and then put those data inside a xml file for some network operation.

Now the thing is, I believe I'm not correctly reading(refer to below method) the pdf file into memory buffer. After reading the pdf the data, what I'm getting into character buffer and passed to encoder method is returning some base64 encoded string, but while decoding it, fails to restore the original data.

I'm getting binary data inside char buffer as shown below:
[image]

Anyone point me out something?

```
void readBinaryFile()
{
  ifstream in("sampleFile.pdf", ios::binary);
  in.seekg(0, ios::end);
  int iSize = in.tellg();
  in.seekg(0, ios::beg);

  char* pBuff = new char[iSize];
  memset(pBuff, 0, sizeof(pBuff));
  in.read(pBuff, iSize);
  in.close();

  //some more code...
}
```

If I write this buffer data into another file, it works fine to create a pdf file with same content, but this kind of char buffer can't be encoded or decoded properly I guess.

Comment: Why are you setting the buffer to all 0?  This is a wasted effort.

Comment: Thats for initialization. Whats wrong in that?

Comment: Your `read` will overwrite your data, thus the initialization is wasted effort.  This will be noticeable on large buffers.

Comment: What makes you think the problem is in the file reading code? I don't see anything obviously wrong, except for the `sizeof(pBuff)` error which will be harmless as long as the file is at least 8 bytes long.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. The culprit was Encoder-Decoder code. It was not correctly decoding. Used http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html one and its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't tell us what the problem is.
Maybe use unsigned char instead of char:

```
unsigned char * pBuff = new unsigned char [iSize];
```

- check if allocations is ok

Maybe the problem is when you call your encoder or decoder, and not in the data reading code.

Comment: Well. std::read won't allowing to read into unsigned char buffer. I tried with MFC CFile using unsigned one. But no use.

Comment: Could you write pseudo code used to execute encoding/decoding ops? Are the functions from a standard library or your own?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this:

```
memset(pBuff, 0, sizeof(pBuff));
```

Since `pBuff` is a `char*`, the `sizeof(pBuff)` is going to return the sizeof a `char*`, which is usually 4 or 8 bytes.

What you want is:

```
memset(pBuff, 0, iSize);
```

But as others have stated, there is no need to initialize the buffer to 0.  You're going to be reading a PDF file, which can contain embedded NULLs anyway, so setting the buffer to 0 is a wasteful effort.

However, to improve a litte bit of the code, you could do this:

```
#include <vector>
void readBinaryFile()
{
  ifstream in("sampleFile.pdf", ios::binary);
  in.seekg(0, ios::end);
  int iSize = in.tellg();
  in.seekg(0, ios::beg);

  std::vector<char> pBuff(iSize);
  if ( iSize > 0 )
      in.read(&pBuff[0], iSize);
  in.close();
}
```

Now, there is no chance of a memory leak occurring.

Comment: Yes thats a point I corrected in my code but see my main post (edited) image. It's storing binary data in char buffer like that which causing a encode-decode problem.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but this poke 4 zeros in the buffer, before the read, so no semantic bug is there

Comment: @PLearner Are you trying to *encode* that stream to Base64?  If so, there is nothing wrong with that stream.  Base64 is designed to encode data that may have control characters and embedded nulls.  So I don't see what your issue is really.

Comment: This is not the issue in the original code. As I suppose in my answer, the issue must be searched in the encoder/decoder code, that is not showed in the question. And, after a while, the problem is exactly in the Encoder/Decoder.